# Returning to Windows 10 after I've installed Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10

I've read that the license stays in the bios. I've got a year old t480s which I'd like to return to Windows 10. I've installed Linux Ubuntu (everything else wiped) and am curious whether this is possible and is violating any terms? Maybe I can also use this ISO - [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Thanks for any help and sorry if the question is repeated!

Answer (score 0):

*whether this is possible and is violating any terms?*

That depends on if Windows 10 was running before installing Linux. If so, then it is now essentially the same as replacing a hard disk (or SSD) and you can now install Windows without violating terms. The licensing information should remain in the Microsoft License server

Comment: Yes, there was an original windows 10 on it. Forgot which version though.

Comment: You can install the new Windows 10 version and it will work

Comment: @КристиянКацаров Do you still have the Windows license sticker under the machine? It should state the version.